# jquery each not staying contained

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with .each(), i'm trying to iterate over multiple span#obj and use the information from the selection list name=instance_type as a data variable in name=instance_input.

I have it working for a single iteration but if i remove the 'return false' from the .each() the data variable becomes filled with the value of the last name=instance_type.

```
$( "span#obj" ).each(function(){

    self = this;

    $("[name='instance_input']",this).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "json_lookup_call.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        dataClass : $("[name='instance_type'] :selected",self).val(),
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
                            return {
                                label: item.reference + (item.name ? " - " + item.name : ""),
                                value: item.reference
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 3
        });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var self = this;
```

otherwise you would create a global variable and only the last one would be used, because every iteration overwrites the previous one.

Comment: Thank You, its the simplest things that always get over looked.

Comment: Yes, if you're too deep into your own code, you lose the focus on simple aspects. Please accept my answer if it helped you solving your problem :)